# Which Visual Studio $variable is the .exe?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Which Visual Studio (2010 (Professional (64-bit (on Windows 7 (Professional (64-bit)))))) points to the `.exe` name?

Some examples of variables are:

```
Variable             Sample value
===================  =============================
$(TargetPath)        C:\...\obj\Debug\Project1.exe
$(ItemPath)          C:\...\Project1.csproj
$(SolutionFileName)  Solution1.sln`
$(ProjectFileName)   Project1.csproj
```

i need the *executable*, e.g.:

```
$(ExePath)           C:\...\Bin\Debug\Project1.exe
```

Except `$(ExePath)` is something i just made up.

> **Note**:
>
> `$(TargetPath)` references the **obj** path. i need the target **bin** path

Comment: If you're editing a pre/post build event, the macro editor will give you examples for each variable.

Comment: Wow, what's with the parentheses? :)

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm, to avoid the 'Missing Parenthesis Error' ;) . Ian is a terrific programmer i guess ;)

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm i didn't know which additional information might be important (or irrelevant) to the question. And then, yes, i had to the close parentheses. ( :) )

Comment: Relevant: http://xkcd.com/541/

Answer (score 0):

`$(TargetPath)` is the application to run eg. in the debugger

Comment: That references the one in the `obj` folder, as opposed to the needed `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all variable by go to project Properties/Build Events/ Edit Pre- or Post-build... and click on Macros >> button.

Specially for builded .exe you need $(TargetPath)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it's `$(TargetPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official variable for the path to `.exe` in `bin` directory, but you can use

```
$(BinDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)
```

to achieve the same effect.